# LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [a4]

Tags: errors, warnings, miktex2.9

The file was working properly then suddenly it gives me this warning LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [a4].
I tried to undo the last action but it didn't help and now I can't create the pdf file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The message you report is not an error but a warning -- and a pretty harmless one at that. If your document no longer compiles, it *must* be because of something else that has changed in your document since the last time it did compile fully.

Comment: Usually the option for A4 paper setup is called `a4paper` and not `a4`. (But you may well be using a non-standard class where `a4` either is - or used to be - accepted.)